# How to skip password typing for Git against Kerberos?

Tags: linux, git, tfs, kerberos

I have a problem with git clone from TFS. Client is Ubuntu 14.04,
TFS certificates are available because https works properly. Proxy is unset in Git and global env.

Working scenarios:

```
A. git clone https://url.to.my.tfs/       
B. git clone https://user@url.to.my.tfs/
```

A. requests username and password, type them, all proceed good.
B. Git don't request a password. Cloning is proceed good. So communication linux(git)-kerberos(TFS) is already OK.

Modified A.) pressed `Enter` when git request for username and password I get:

`fatal: Authentication failed for https://url.to.my.tfs`

So, where is the problem? How to skip password typing?

Comment: The whole purpose of kerberos is so you don't have to type a username/password. The server coordinates it so the server side can run as the client account without passing anything. Not even a hash. That's why it is so secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fatal: Authentication failed for...` is exactly because of that you didn't type user/pass when requested.

And `git clone https://user@url.to.my.tfs/` and no password requests from Git can be because of Git `credential.helper` cache used on HTTPS protocols. 
https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

This answered question relates to HTTPS on Github but it also applies to your scenario. [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github/5343146#5343146)
There you can find option that suits you best.

Comment: Ok, it make sens - I will try this tommorow, but this is only way to skip typing username/password? Git can't resolve actually logged user using kerberos tickets?

Ubuntu is connected to the same AD as TFS and I use domain user for this operations.